# Difference between convergent in Measure and convergent a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, pointwise-convergence

I’m thinking about two problems:

In $L^2([0,1],dx);$

1. If $f_n\rightarrow f$ In $L^2$, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ In measure.
2. If $f_n\rightarrow f$ In $L^2$, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ Almost everywhere.

So I know the definition of convergence in measure is:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu(\{x\in X: \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\lvert\geq\epsilon\})=0$, $\forall\epsilon>0.$

So can I prove the first one by 
$\int\lvert f_n-f\lvert= \lvert \lvert f_n-f\lvert\lvert_1\leq\lvert\lvert f_n-f\lvert\lvert_2\cdot\lvert\lvert 1\lvert\lvert_2\rightarrow0$
Therefore $\lvert f_n-f\lvert\rightarrow0,$ (since it’s positive) this means it’s convergent in measure?

But what’s the difference of convergent almost everywhere? Thanks.

Comment: What's our space. Why do you think that $||1||_2$ is finite

Comment: Oops, sorry sorry, forgot to type in the space

Comment: Yes, $|f_n-f|\to 0$, BUT a. e. Convergence a. e. implies convergence in measure

Comment: Is $\mu$ the standard Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect because $f_n>0$ and $\int f_n\to 0$ do not imply $f_n\to 0$ a.e.

Let $f_{n,k}$ be the characteristic function of $[(k-1)/n,k/n]$, $k=1,\ldots,n$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. Rearrange it into a usual sequence: 
$$g_1=f_{1,1},\ g_2=f_{2,1},\ g_3=f_{2,2},\ g_4=f_{3,1},\ g_5=f_{3,2},\ \ldots$$

It is easy to see that $g_n\to 0$ in $L^2$ but $g_n(x)\not\to 0$ for all $x$.

The first implication (convergence in norm implies convergence in measure) is correct, which follows easily from [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).

Comment: I see about the counter example. About Chebyshev’s inequality, we have $\mu(\{x\in X:\lvert f_n-f\lvert\geq \epsilon\})\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon^p}\int_{\lvert f_n-f\lvert\geq \epsilon}\lvert f_n-f\lvert^p$,the norm part goes to zero, but the fraction goes to infinity?

Comment: @Areedd No, $\epsilon$ is fixed. You only let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks!